# Inconsistent keyboard notifications when presenting a view controller

Tags: ios, keyboard, modalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller, custom-transition

I have a view controller `A` which is currently in editing mode, i.e. it has a text field that is currently the first responder.

[image: Transition with visible keyboard]

Now I present view controller `B` from `A` with a custom animator:

```
class Animator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 1
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        print("-----  Transition Animation BEGIN -----")
        guard let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to) else {
            return
        }
        transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(toView)
        print("-----  Transition Animation ADDED SUBVIEW -----")
        toView.frame = transitionContext.containerView.bounds
        toView.layoutIfNeeded()
        transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
    }     
}
```

For reasons of simplicity, this animator doesn't animate much: It only adds the destination view controller's view to the hierarchy and that's it.

View controller `B` has a text field as well and when it appears on screen, I want it to become the first responder immediately. Thus I added this code to view controller `B`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Now the interesting part is what happens between

```
-----  Transition Animation BEGIN -----
```

and

```
-----  Transition Animation ADDED SUBVIEW -----
```

#### 1. Inside Rootview

When the text field in view controller `A` is placed anywhere **inside its root view**, these are the keyboard notifications I receive from `NotificationCenter`:

```
-----  Transition Animation BEGIN -----
UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification
UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification
UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification
UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
-----  Transition Animation ADDED SUBVIEW -----
```

In other words: Adding the destination view controller's view to the transition's container view causes all these keyboard notifications to be fired. This is great because afterwards I can update `B`'s layout to account for the keyboard and also apply these layout changes to my transition animation.

#### 2. Inside collection view cell

When the text field is placed **inside a collection view cell** of view controller `A`, however, no keyboard notifications are received during the transition:

```
-----  Transition Animation BEGIN -----
-----  Transition Animation ADDED SUBVIEW -----
```

In *any case*, these are the notifications I receive *before* the transition animation begins:

```
UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification
UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
```

This is problematic as in the second scenario view controller `B` still "thinks" that the keyboard is hidden during the animation. Thus, I cannot layout its view and create the correct animations.

#### Any idea why the keyboard notifications aren't fired in scenario 2 and how I can fix that?

Comment: Can you provide a sample code on github or something ?

Comment: I just figured out that it's got nothing to do with the collection view at all. It happens with every text field / text view as soon as I assign a custom view to its `inputAccessoryView` property. Seems to me like a system bug. Will investigate further...

Comment: @GaétanZ: Here's a sample project: https://github.com/mischa-hildebrand/KeyboardNotificationsBug.

Comment: Hm this does sound like a bug to me. Worth reporting at bugreport.apple.com.